# $x^4-3x^3-9x^2+2=0$, why does wolframalpha give complex solutions when they are real?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Although  $x^4-3x^3-9x^2+2=y$ intersects with the $x$-axis $4$ times (this is shown in the graph) [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-3x%5E3-9x%5E2%2b2=0) gives me complex solutions. Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Click "more digits" and the problem will more or less disappear; the imaginary part will be $0\times 10^{-x}$, where $x$ gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Algorithms for computing explicit roots to general polynomials of order 3 or 4 [require complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). Even for a polynomial with three real roots, these complex numbers cancel out in the end.

However, due to numerical precision issues, evaluating these computations on any finite precision computer will leave an error. The complex part in the answers are less than the machine epsilon (around $2.26 \times 10^{-16}$), so that's basically what's happening here.

Comment: You might want to look at the Wikipedia articles on the cubic and quartic equation, and at the special article on the Casus Irreducibilis.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for the comment; I could not remember the exact term for *casus irreducibilis* :)

Comment: @Arkamis: I'm pretty sure Wolfram Alpha uses an arbitrary precision library for its calculations, so the machine epsilon is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: @nightcracker It probably does, but at the same time it probably truncates that precision based on the number of decimal places to display, which is why vadim's comment exhibits the behavior it does. It might not be the Machine epsilon, but it's something basically the same.